# restful put method getting wrong result in codeigniter?

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, restful-url, codeigniter-restserver

I'm creating the android app for my code igniter web site and i want to save data through restful web service but when i send request to my put method it's giving me wrong result.

this is my to view the result.

```
$data = $this->request->body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    print_r($data);
```

**Result:**

------WebKitFormBoundary1FuQsccaxrxHWI5A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="1"

name
------WebKitFormBoundary1FuQsccaxrxHWI5A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="2"

address
------WebKitFormBoundary1FuQsccaxrxHWI5A--

**this is my request body:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get data from post

**Example**

```
$data = $_POST['name'];
```